# JQuery Validation Uncaught typeError when applying custom message to remote validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate remotely whether a string already exists on the server using the `jqueryvalidation.org plugin.`

**Here is my jQuery code:**

```
$("#title").rules("add", {
    "remote": {
        url: checkTitleAvailable.php,    // echoes "true" or "false"
        type: "post",
        data: {
            proposedSeoTitle:function() {
                return $('#title').val();
            }
        },
        complete: function(response) {
            if (response.responseText != "true" && response.responseText != "false") {
                alert("unexpected response " + response.responseText);
            }
            return response;
        }
    },
    "messages": {"remote": "That title already exists"}
});
```

('title' is an input field with id="title" class="required")

**I get an error:**

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined".

`"messages"` gets treated as another rule, but there is no function to run. Yet it still gets treated as a message, and tends to pop up when it should, but the error makes the whole system unusable - it is impossible to validate the whole page before saving it.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug within the Validation plugin? Is there some workaround? Should I be looking to hack the plugin to get it working?

Comment: Also read my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855214/jquery-remote-validation-doesnt-block-form-submit

Comment: Hi Sparky, your other answer certainly has given me some further leads to chase down, but I have still not managed to get it working.  I still think there is a bug in the plugin, but I hope I'm wrong.  It seems really neat that the server-side call can echo something back that ends up as the custom message.  Looking forward to seeing your response, meanwhile if I get it working I will post my answer.  I also should mention that I have extra data I need to pass across (so just defaulting to the field's val is not an option for me).  I left it out for clarity.

Comment: This is a very popular plugin, so if you think there's a bug, then check over at github.  Meanwhile, I doubt it.  Are you using the latest version of the plugin?  Any bugs that have been found in the past can only be fixed by updating the plugin.

Comment: Typically, the reported error indicates a user error.   Can you also show the relevant HTML markup?

Comment: Your description is lacking.  Are you saying that it works fine without the `messages` option?

Comment: Thanks Sparky.  It seems to be working fine now.  I had tried before with and without messages, different handlers etc.  And my markup does have a name - I knew the plugin needed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> 'title' is an input field with `id="title" class="required"`

Even though you're using the `.rules('add')` method to declare your rules on the field, the plugin still mandates that every input field have a (*unique*) `name` attribute.  It's how the plugin keeps track of inputs.

See the **Markup recommendations** section of the [Reference Docs page](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/)...

> The name attribute is 'required' for input elements, the validation plugin doesn't work without it.

---

Your code:

```
"remote": {
    url: checkTitleAvailable.php,    // echoes "true" or "false"
    type: "post",
    data: {
        proposedSeoTitle:function() {
            return $('#title').val();
        }
    },
    complete: function(response) {
        if (response.responseText != "true" && response.responseText != "false") {
            alert("unexpected response " + response.responseText);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with the `complete` callback here.  The plugin's `remote` rule is automatically evaluating the response from the server, but yet you're also evaluating if the response is boolean and returning the response.

[As per the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/), the `remote` method is looking for `true` for a validated field.  Or when the server response is a `false`, `undefined`, `null`, or a string, it's evaluated as an invalid field, where the string itself over-rides the default error message.  Given that the plugin already evaluates the server response, you would never need to manually evaluate the response using a `complete` callback.  Otherwise, you might as well write your own `remote` method from scratch instead of using the one from the plugin.

> The serverside resource is called via jQuery.ajax (XMLHttpRequest) and
>   gets a key/value pair corresponding to the name of the validated
>   element and its value as a GET parameter. The **response is evaluated as
>   JSON and must be `true` for valid elements, and can be any `false`,
>   `undefined` or `null` for invalid elements**, using the default message; or
>   a string, eg. "That name is already taken, try peter123 instead" to
>   display as the error message.

Remove your `complete` callback and see what happens.

```
remote: { // <-- quotation marks not required.
    url: checkTitleAvailable.php,    // echoes "true" or "false"
    type: "post",
    data: {
        proposedSeoTitle:function() {
            return $('#title').val();
        }
    }
},
messages: { // <-- quotation marks not required.
    // quotation marks not required around `remote`.
    remote: "That title already exists"
}
```

**BTW** - quotation marks around `rules`, `messages` and other options is not required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it.  Unfortunately I am still getting errors.  It might be a couple of days before I have time to investigate again.  I'll ask another question if I need to.